# JavaScript canvas image generation add spacing between letters

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I need your help. I'm currently trying to write a text 2 png library to generate PNGs including inline styling for every single letter. Currently I'm really stuck trying to add a spacing between each letter. At the moment every letter is written like in layers above each one:

[image]

Do you have any good ideas how to do this? At the end the letters should be beside each other including the option to pass a letter spacing to modify the spacing later - like line spacing:

```
let text = '{#ff0000ES}\n{#FF33F0AC}\nR'

fs.writeFileSync('test2.png', text2png(text,
    {
        color: 'gray',
        textAlign: 'center',
        lineSpacing: 30,
        letterSpacing: 10, // <-- needed
        font: '100px sans-serif'
    }
));
```

This is the function I'm working with:

```
const {registerFont, createCanvas} = require("canvas");

/**
 * Convert text to PNG image.
 * @param text
 * @param [options]
 * @param [options.font="30px sans-serif"] css style font
 * @param [options.textAlign="left"] text alignment (left, center, right)
 * @param [options.color="black"] (or options.textColor) text color
 * @param [options.backgroundColor] (or options.bgColor) background color
 * @param [options.lineSpacing=0]
 * @param [options.letterSpacing=0]
 * @param [options.strokeWidth=0]
 * @param [options.strokeColor='white']
 * @param [options.padding=0] width of the padding area (left, top, right, bottom)
 * @param [options.paddingLeft]
 * @param [options.paddingTop]
 * @param [options.paddingRight]
 * @param [options.paddingBottom]
 * @param [options.borderWidth=0] width of border (left, top, right, bottom)
 * @param [options.borderLeftWidth=0]
 * @param [options.borderTopWidth=0]
 * @param [options.borderRightWidth=0]
 * @param [options.borderBottomWidth=0]
 * @param [options.borderColor="black"] border color
 * @param [options.localFontPath] path to local font (e.g. fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf)
 * @param [options.localFontName] name of local font (e.g. Lobster)
 * @param [options.output="buffer"] 'buffer', 'stream', 'dataURL', 'canvas's
 * @returns {string} png image buffer
 */
const text2png = (text, options = {}) => {
    // Options
    options = parseOptions(options);

    // Register a custom font
    if (options.localFontPath && options.localFontName) {
        registerFont(options.localFontPath, {family: options.localFontName});
    }

    const canvas = createCanvas(0, 0);
    const ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const max = {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        ascent: 0,
        descent: 0
    };

    let lastDescent;
    const lineProps = text.split("\n").map(line => {
        ctx.font      = options.font;
        const metrics = ctx.measureText(line);

        const left    = -1 * metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft;
        const right   = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight;
        const ascent  = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent;
        const descent = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;

        max.left    = Math.max(max.left, left);
        max.right   = Math.max(max.right, right);
        max.ascent  = Math.max(max.ascent, ascent);
        max.descent = Math.max(max.descent, descent);
        lastDescent = descent;

        return {line, left, right, ascent, descent};
    });

    const lineHeight = max.ascent + max.descent + options.lineSpacing;

    const contentWidth  = max.left + max.right;
    const contentHeight =
              lineHeight * lineProps.length -
              options.lineSpacing -
              (max.descent - lastDescent);

    canvas.width =
        contentWidth +
        options.borderLeftWidth +
        options.borderRightWidth +
        options.paddingLeft +
        options.paddingRight;

    canvas.height =
        contentHeight +
        options.borderTopWidth +
        options.borderBottomWidth +
        options.paddingTop +
        options.paddingBottom;

    const hasBorder =
              false ||
              options.borderLeftWidth ||
              options.borderTopWidth ||
              options.borderRightWidth ||
              options.borderBottomWidth;

    if (hasBorder) {
        ctx.fillStyle = options.borderColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    if (options.backgroundColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = options.backgroundColor;
        ctx.fillRect(
            options.borderLeftWidth,
            options.borderTopWidth,
            canvas.width - (options.borderLeftWidth + options.borderRightWidth),
            canvas.height - (options.borderTopWidth + options.borderBottomWidth)
        );
    } else if (hasBorder) {
        ctx.clearRect(
            options.borderLeftWidth,
            options.borderTopWidth,
            canvas.width - (options.borderLeftWidth + options.borderRightWidth),
            canvas.height - (options.borderTopWidth + options.borderBottomWidth)
        );
    }

    ctx.font        = options.font;
    ctx.antialias   = "gray";
    ctx.textAlign   = options.textAlign;
    ctx.lineWidth   = options.strokeWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.strokeColor;

    let offsetY = options.borderTopWidth + options.paddingTop;
    lineProps.forEach(lineProp => {
        // Calculate Y
        let x = 0;
        let y = max.ascent + offsetY;

        // Calculate X
        switch (options.textAlign) {
            case "start":
            case "left":
                x = lineProp.left + options.borderLeftWidth + options.paddingLeft;
                break;

            case "end":
            case "right":
                x =
                    canvas.width -
                    lineProp.left -
                    options.borderRightWidth -
                    options.paddingRight;
                break;

            case "center":
                x = contentWidth / 2 + options.borderLeftWidth + options.paddingLeft;
                break;
        }

        let linePropIterator = 0;
        let stylingChars     = '{}';
        let subtext          = '';
        let textColor        = options.textColor;

        while (linePropIterator < lineProp.line.length) {
            let wordCharCode = lineProp.line.charCodeAt(linePropIterator);
            let word         = lineProp.line[linePropIterator];

            if (wordCharCode < 256) {
                if (stylingChars.indexOf(word) > -1) {
                    if (word === '{') {
                        textColor = lineProp.line.substr(linePropIterator + 1, 7);

                        linePropIterator += 7;
                    } else if (word === '}') {
                        textColor = options.textColor;
                    }
                } else {
                    subtext += word;
                }

                if (subtext !== '') {
                    renderText(subtext);

                    subtext = '';
                }

                linePropIterator += 1;
            }
        }

        function renderText(text) {
            ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            ctx.fillText(text, x + randomInt(20, 50), y); // <-- Random int seems to change the spacing but how to calculate it?

            if (options.strokeWidth > 0) {
                ctx.strokeText(lineProp.line, x, y);
            }
        }

        offsetY += lineHeight;
    });

    switch (options.output) {
        case "buffer":
            return canvas.toBuffer();
        case "stream":
            return canvas.createPNGStream();
        case "dataURL":
            return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        case "canvas":
            return canvas;
        default:
            throw new Error(`output type:${options.output} is not supported.`);
    }
};

function parseOptions(options) {
    return {
        font: or(options.font, "30px sans-serif"),
        textAlign: or(options.textAlign, "left"),
        textColor: or(options.textColor, options.color, "black"),
        backgroundColor: or(options.bgColor, options.backgroundColor, null),
        lineSpacing: or(options.lineSpacing, 0),
        letterSpacing: or(options.letterSpacing, 0),

        strokeWidth: or(options.strokeWidth, 0),
        strokeColor: or(options.strokeColor, "white"),

        paddingLeft: or(options.paddingLeft, options.padding, 0),
        paddingTop: or(options.paddingTop, options.padding, 0),
        paddingRight: or(options.paddingRight, options.padding, 0),
        paddingBottom: or(options.paddingBottom, options.padding, 0),

        borderLeftWidth: or(options.borderLeftWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderTopWidth: or(options.borderTopWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderBottomWidth: or(options.borderBottomWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderRightWidth: or(options.borderRightWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderColor: or(options.borderColor, "black"),

        localFontName: or(options.localFontName, null),
        localFontPath: or(options.localFontPath, null),

        output: or(options.output, "buffer")
    };
}

function or() {
    for (let arg of arguments) {
        if (typeof arg !== "undefined") {
            return arg;
        }
    }
    return arguments[arguments.length - 1];
}

function randomInt(e, t) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (t - e + 1) + e)
}

module.exports = text2png;
```

I've tried to change the x value with a random int value which seems to be a part of the solution but how to calculate now the x value by respecting the letterSpacing option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't quite get to the end of your code, since the snippet you contributed is rather comprehensive... But I believe what you're looking for is the `measureText()` Method of the canvas context. It returns the width the given String would have, if it were displayed on the canvas; you can read more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp).

I guess you could use this method to calculate the offsets needed for the different letters. Since `measureText()` already considers the font type you won't have to worry about different char widths...

Comment: But somehow I need to calculate the position to place each letter. Originally I've printed it out line by line which was no problem but for letter coloration I needed to change it to word by word.

Comment: In case of left alignment you could simply add the letter width to the x position each time. For center alignment you would need to calculate the width of the entire String at first, so you can substract half of that length from the center x position for the first letter...

Comment: With this tip and some tone of coffee I've managed to create spacing. Thanks!